# UIRefreshControl How to detect if a user begins to drag down?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uirefreshcontrol

I have a `UIRefreshControl` in a `UITableViewController`. Is there any way I can detect if a user begins to drag the View down to refresh the content? 
I do not mean the `beginRefreshing` method. I want to be able to detect when a user begins to drag down - like when the circle fills up before the `beginRefreshing` method is called. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

As you have implemented `UITableViewDelegate` protocol you can also implement [`UIScrollViewDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html) which is called on scroll or drag.

**Objective C**

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

or

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

**Swift**

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView)
```

or

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView)
```

Implement `UIRefreshControl` without  `UITableViewController`
    Add a scrollview and put this code in your `viewDidLoad`

```
let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
 refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")
        refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: "refresh:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
        ScrollView.addSubview(refreshControl)
        ScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 800)
```

Add this method

```
func refresh (sender:AnyObject)
    {
        print("Refresh")
    }
```

Comment: But when I include the scrollViewWillBeginDragging or scrollViewDidScroll method, it will call these methods when I scroll in den TableView - how do I reference the methods to only the refreshControl and not the TableView itself?

Comment: On scroll, look at the `contentOffset.y` value if the scroll view (i.e., table view). That will tell you if the user is "rubber-banding" the table beyond the top limit (= preparation for refresh), or just scrolling the table.

Comment: @NicolasMiari can you leave an example?